# Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ the minimal field that contains $0$ and $1$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ the minimal field that contains $0$ and $1$ ?

Why isn't it $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: I think you need to supply some context.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "0" and "1".

Comment: I don't think it is.  I think it is the minimal *ordered field*.   An ordered field has conditions Z 2 doesn't satisfy.

Comment: This is definitely *Not* a duplicate.  The other question has *nothing* to do with this. The other question is what Z2 isn't a prime subfield of all fields.  This is why the field Z2 itself is not in and of itself, not the smallest field.  That's an entirely different question.

Comment: I think Z2 *IS* the minimal minimal field. But Z2 is not an ordered field. An ordered field requires that if a < b then a + c < a + c. If 0 < 1 then 1 = 1+0 < 1+ 1 =0 and vice versa. So 0 < 1 iff 1 < 0 violating trichotom|.

Comment: @fleablood Since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't embed into $\mathbb{Q}$, I would definitely **not** say that it is "the" minimal field; I think cardinality is definitely the wrong thing to use here.

Comment: Misconception. $\Bbb{Q}$ is **a** minimal field containing $0$ and $1$. So are $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ for all primes $p$. But none of these fields is a subset of any of the others, so it is IMHO wrong to use the definite article. They are all minimal subfields, because none contain smaller fields. That's what *a prime field* means.

Comment: I think the OP should **really** clarify what, exactly, they mean . . .

Comment: Nowhere in the question did the OP specify the minimal field that embeds into Q, but simply "the minimal field".  Without context I took that the mean simply the smallest possible field with all nescessary elements and no extraneous elements or conditions.  That would be Z2.  If however she meant the minimal subfield of some other field then this *is* a duplicate.

Comment: Likewise nowhere did the OP use "prime field".  I honestly assumed she meant minimal field satisfying all field axioms.  Which is Z2.  As she mentioned Q I honestly assumed her mistake was not mention *ordered* field, of which Q is the minimal.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "$0$" and "$1$" (and also by "minimal").

If "$0$" and "$1$" refer to the real numbers zero and one, then in essence you're asking, "Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ the minimal *subfield of $\mathbb{R}$* containing $0$ and $1$?" To answer this, note that $\{0, 1\}$ is *not* a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$; it's not closed under addition ($1+1\not\in\{0, 1\}$) and it doesn't have additive inverses ($-1\not\in\{0, 1\}$). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906750/why-arent-all-prime-subfields-equal-to-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

On the other hand, if "$0$" and "$1$" *don't* refer to the real numbers zero and one, but rather just the additive and multiplicative identity in any field - then yes, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the smallest field in terms of cardinality. However, note that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed into $\mathbb{Q}$! The map sending $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$ is **not** a homomorphism. So in that sense, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are incomparable. Indeed, $\mathbb{Q}$ has no proper subfields, so I would say it is *a* minimal field.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the "minimal field" is $\mathbb{Q}$, other times it is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime number $p$.  It depends on what the characteristic of your ambient field is.

By definition, any field $F$ must contain elements called $0_F$ and $1_F$ (or just $0$ and $1$), which are not equal and which satisfy $0+x=x$ and $1 \cdot x = x$ for all $x \in F$.

Let $F$ be a field.  The *characteristic* of $F$ is the smallest number of times you have to add $1$ to itself to get $0$.  If this never happens, then we say that *$F$ has characteristic zero*.  Otherwise, you can show that the characteristic of $F$ has to be a prime number.

If the characteristic of $F$ is a prime number, say $p$, then you can show that the subset $\{0, 1, 2, ... , p-1\} \subseteq F$  is actually a field.  Let's denote that field by $F_p$.   If $K$ is any subfield of $F$ whatsoever, it is easy to see that $F_p \subseteq K$, because $K$ must contain $0$ and $1$, and hence $1+1, 1+1+1$ etc.  Furthermore, there is an  isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow F_p$.

On the other hand, if the characteristic of $F$ is zero, then the set $R_0  =\{0,1,-1,2,-2, ...\}$ is a sub*ring* of $F$ which is obviously isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $F$ is a field, the inverses of the nonzero elements of $F$ exist, are unique, and are elements of $F$.  Therefore,

$$F_0 := \{ \frac{x}{y} : x, y \in R_0, y \neq 0 \}$$ is a subfield of $F$.  If $K$ is any subfield of $F$ whatsoever, it is easy to see that $F_0 \subseteq K$, because $K$ must contain $0$ and $1$, hence $-1,2,-2$ etc. as well as the inverses of these elements.  Furthermore, there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow F_0$.  Let me know if you have any questions about this.